# Leaflet showing error in developer tool "t.on is not a function"

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have problem when i am using leaflet library 1.0.3 and it works fine and show no error or warning when it is 0.7.7 i have using following libraries:

- angular 1.5.8
- angular material 1.1.3
- angular-leaflet-directive 0.10.0
- leaflet - 1.0.3

My map is visible properly even the marker cluster is working fine but in developer tool it is showing me error like these

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) is already quite old, the latest release version [`v0.10.0`](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/releases/tag/v0.10.0) dates from 2015, when Leaflet was still in 0.x.x version.

There are breaking changes when upgrading to Leaflet version 1.x.x.

Since you seem to say that your app still behaves correctly, except for the error in the browser console, then either you can live with it, or downgrade to Leaflet 0.7.7.

You can also get ride of angular-leaflet-directive and directly use Leaflet 1.x.x with AngularJS.